# How can I programmatically read metadata from an AWS S3 Object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata

My app is storing files on AWS S3.  When the files are retrieved, some of them are missing a metadata field.  I'd like to write a service that lets me check the files to see if the metadata field is present and valid after they have been retrieved from S3.  I feel like it should be as simple as `my_object.show_metadata`, but I'm having trouble tracking down the solution.  There is a `AWS::S3::Object#metadata` method, but when I try to use it I get the following error:

> *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `set?' for # < Hash::0x007ffa547a9350>

Any insight or questions to help me find my blind spot on this one is appreciated.

UPDATE:  The issue has been resolved.  The correct way of doing what this question asks is in fact the `AWS::S3::Object#metadata` method.  The issue in this case is the permissions must be explicitly set when the S3 object is created.  Before the fix:

```
Aws::S3::Object.new(
  region: 'us-east-1',
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  bucket_name: "foo",
  key: key
)
```

After the fix:

```
Aws.config.update({
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
})

Aws::S3::Object.new(
  region: 'us-east-1',
  bucket_name: "foo",
  key: key
)
```

After adjusting my code I was able to use all of the AWS S3 methods successfully, including `#metadata`.

Comment: It's a good idea for you to add your edit as an answer and accept it. That way people can see that this question has an answer in search results.

Comment: @TomManterfield Thanks, still learning the ropes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing what this question asks is in fact the AWS::S3::Object#metadata method. The issue in this case is the permissions must be explicitly set when the S3 object is created. Before the fix:

```
Aws::S3::Object.new(   
    region: 'us-east-1',   
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],   
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],   
    bucket_name: "foo",   
    key: key 
)
```

After the fix:

```
Aws.config.update({   
    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], 
    ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']) 
}) 

Aws::S3::Object.new(   
    region: 'us-east-1',   
    bucket_name: "foo",  
    key: key 
)
```

After adjusting my code I was able to use all of the AWS S3 methods successfully, including #metadata.